# Python Script to ping a list of specified hosts in a .txt file

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I am working on a script that would allow me to ping multiple hosts to check their status. Currently I am getting 2 errors while running the below script which I've found online. I am more of a network engineer rather than programmer. I have just started learning python but basics don't help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance for your help

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/p.petryszen/Documents/VsCode/Scripts/ping_hosts/ping_hosts.py", line 45, in 
pending = Queue.Queue()
AttributeError: type object 'Queue' has no attribute 'Queue'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/p.petryszen/Documents/VsCode/Scripts/ping_hosts/ping_hosts.py", line 45, in 
pending = Queue.Queue()
AttributeError: type object 'Queue' has no attribute 'Queue'

```
import sys
import os
import platform
import subprocess
from queue import Queue 
import threading

def worker_func(pingArgs, pending, done):
    try:
        while True:
            # Get the next address to ping.
            address = pending.get_nowait()

            ping = subprocess.Popen(ping_args + [address],
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.PIPE
            )
            out, error = ping.communicate()

            # Output the result to the 'done' queue.
            done.put((out, error))
    except Queue.Empty:
        # No more addresses.
        pass
    finally:
        # Tell the main thread that a worker is about to terminate.
        done.put(None)

# The number of workers.
NUM_WORKERS = 4

plat = platform.system()
scriptDir = sys.path[0]
hosts = os.path.join(scriptDir, 'hosts.txt')

# The arguments for the 'ping', excluding the address.
if plat == "Windows":
    pingArgs = ["ping", "-n", "1", "-l", "1", "-w", "100"]
elif plat == "Linux":
    pingArgs = ["ping", "-c", "1", "-l", "1", "-s", "1", "-W", "1"]
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown platform")

# The queue of addresses to ping.
pending = Queue.Queue()

# The queue of results.
done = Queue.Queue()

# Create all the workers.
workers = []
for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS):
    workers.append(threading.Thread(target=worker_func, args=(pingArgs, pending, done)))

# Put all the addresses into the 'pending' queue.
with open(hosts, "r") as hostsFile:
    for line in hostsFile:
        pending.put(line.strip())

# Start all the workers.
for w in workers:
    w.daemon = True
    w.start()

# Print out the results as they arrive.
numTerminated = 0
while numTerminated < NUM_WORKERS:
    result = done.get()
    if result is None:
        # A worker is about to terminate.
        numTerminated += 1
    else:
        print(result[0]) # out
        print(result[1]) # error

# Wait for all the workers to terminate.
for w in workers:
    w.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

With `from queue import Queue` you imported only the object Queue in your script, so if you want to create a new instance of a queue you can directly use `Queue()`, this means you would have:

```py
from queue import Queue

# The queue of addresses to ping.
pending = Queue()

# The queue of results.
done = Queue()
```

If you instead import module queue as a whole you would need to specify where the object Queue comes from

```
import queue
# The queue of addresses to ping.
pending = queue.Queue()

# The queue of results.
done = queue.Queue()
```

For more references in modules:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: and worth pointing out, queue module used to be "Queue" pre- 3.0 python

Comment: I'm not familiar with queue, what's the current standard?

Comment: like in your example.

Comment: Still getting the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/p.petryszen/Documents/VsCode/Scripts/ping_hosts/ping_hosts.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ValueError("Unknown platform")
ValueError: Unknown platform
~
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/p.petryszen/Documents/VsCode/Scripts/ping_hosts/ping_hosts.py", line 53, in <module>
    workers.append(threading.Thread(target=worker_func, args=(pingArgs, pending, done)))
NameError: name 'pingArgs' is not defined